# How to keep ASP.Net application running after closing the web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that do some work on database every specific time, so how can I keep it doing its work even I close the web browser?

Is using a `Thread` useful and will it work for me? What other available solutions?

Comment: Do not use your web application for long-running tasks. That's not what they are meant for. Instead, use a Windows Service or Scheduled Task to perform long-running or periodic operations. Leave the web application for request/response work.

Comment: The application isn't stored locally , it is stored on a hosting space , so i can't use a windows service .

Comment: @AhmadShaheen There is a way to do something similar - http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html, but it is obviously not recommend.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: The `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` can be considered 'advised' in my opinion. Added it to my post.

Comment: Also look at Quartz.Net for running tasks at a specific time.http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to do that. A regular web server process isn't a background worker that runs forever, it replies on requests and it keeps some state. You don't want to let your thread end because of the application pool getting recycled, sessions time out, etc.

You have a few options, which you could use:

- [A Windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the most logical thing to do);
- The new .NET 4.5.2 [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) (which separates itself from the user session context. Note: for short-lived background tasks only! Since 'The `AppDomain` shutdown can only be delayed 90 seconds');
- [Windows Azure Web Jobs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) (for in hosted environments);
- [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).